# Cannot set cookie in PHP 7 after migrating from Godaddy to Google App Engine [Code works on localhost]

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cookies

I cant seem to be able to set cookie in php 7 after migrating to google cloud [app engine] from godaddy where the code below works, it also works on localhost. The code below.

```
$cookier_name = "hello";
setcookie('browsing_tracker', $cookier_name, time() + (3000 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
```

AND

```
$cookier_name = "hello";
setcookie("browsing_tracker", $cookier_name, time()+3000 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
```

**RECAP**: I used this on localhost and godaddy and it worked perfectly, after moving to google app engine it magically stops working, I also made a PHP ini file still no result when I do this

```
echo (isset($_COOKIE['browsing_tracker']) && $_COOKIE['shopping_tracker']=='hello') ? 'enabled' : 'disabled';
```

I get **DISABLED** as response and when I check google chrome and firefox cookie tab, its not there.

PHP ini file

```
session.auto_start = 1
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.cookie_path = /
```

EDIT: Front controller seems to be the culprit, I tested the cookie setting code on the front controller page and the cookie was set, but on localhost and Godaddy we do not use a front controller, that was where the error is, but there should be a way to tell the front controller to pass all cookie creation request to their respective pages where the cookie creation codes are based.

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to an answer given by *someone1*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13571010/11787139

It might have something to do with the way Google App platform handles requests.

Comment: You are right, I noticed that the front controller for google app engine, is the issue, since cookie must be sent first, the front controller does most of the handling.

Comment: I did a minor edit to the question front controller seems to be the culprit

Comment: Good to hear you're one step closer to solving the problem. Please make sure to upvote someone1's answer to give him credits.